# Is there a way to check a SQL snippet validate in web client side?

Tags: sql, validation, client-side

Now my site has a feature which allows user to input some SQL statements.
The statements will exe in backend database later.

Is there a way to check if the SQL is valid in client side?

Comment: "Now my site has a feature which allows user to input some SQL statements" - SQL injection anyone?

Comment: No, no, not SQL injection anyone. what's your site?

Comment: SQL injection is more an unforeseen ability to add SQL.  This is just plain asking people to break stuff.

Comment: you've been a member for 11 months and accepted none of the 13 questions you've asked.

Comment: This obviously is very dangerous.  I hope you realize the risks involved with running user entered sql.  If you want the users to be able to search, then create a screen that lets the users enter the parameters for your parameterized sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can do this with submitting it with ajax :)